# How to default the file name when printing to XPS file in .NET

Tags: .net, printing, xps

When the Microsoft XPS Document Writer is selected for printing from my .NET application, the user is presented with a file dialog where the file name is initially "*.XPS". I'd like it to default to a more useful name instead (ideally, using the document name I am providing).

I read the following question:

[Way to default the name of the generated XPS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196110/way-to-default-the-name-of-the-generated-xps-file)

...and tried setting the PrinterSettings.PrintFileName as suggested in the answers, but it does not seem to work...

```
        PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();

        printDoc.DocumentName = name;
        printDlg.Document = printDoc;
        printDlg.AllowSelection = true;
        printDlg.AllowSomePages = true;

        //Call ShowDialog 

        if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName.Contains("XPS"))
                {
                    printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = name + ".XPS";
                }

                // Actual printing code from this point onward...
```

If I print to Adobe PDF, it defaults the file name to the print document name + ".PDF" (ideal behavior), but the built-in XPS print driver seems to lack this feature, and even seems to be ignoring the PrintFileName property. Am I doing something wrong, or is this an issue with the XPS print driver?

BTW, I am using VS 2010 / .NET 4.0 (both SP1) on Vista Business SP2

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a limitation of the XPS Document Writer.  The [Win2PDF](https://www.win2pdf.com) printer driver can [save as XPS](https://www.win2pdf.com/features.html), and defaults to using the print document name.  You could try using it instead of the Microsoft XPS Document Writer.